# Receive Form Information from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html, http, server

Just going to start off by saying I'm very new to Web Development.

I've created a simple Landing Page that requests user input, and has a button that *should* submit the information to a linked `.php` file. Problem is, I have absolutely no idea if I'm on the right track...

**THE HTML:**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input name="_utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Column">
            <label for="user_first_name">First name</label> <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]"
                                                                   onfocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"
                                                                   placeholder="Geralt"
                                                                   type="text" autofocus required>
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
            <label for="user_last_name">Last name</label> <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]"
                                                                 placeholder="of Rivia" type="text" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Column">
            <label for="user_email">Your Email</label> <input id="user_email" maxlength="200" name="user[email]"
                                                              pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;&#39;*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;&#39;*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
                                                              placeholder="geraltofrivia@email.com" type="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Column">
            <label>How Did You Hear About Us?</label>
            <select id="HDYHAU" name="HDYHAU" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose One</option>
                <option value="Radio Show">Radio Show</option>
                <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
                <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                <option value="Current Client">Current Client</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input id="user_contact_visitor_key" name="user[other][contact_visitor_key]" type="hidden">
    <input id="user_contact_hubspot_utk" name="user[other][contact_hubspot_utk]" type="hidden">
    <input id="auth_app" name="app" type="hidden" value="wistia">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Column">
            <p class="MutedSubtext">By clicking this button, you agree to our <a class="MutedSubtext MutedSubtext__link"
                                                                                 href="https://test.com/terms">Terms
                of Service</a>
                and <a class="MutedSubtext MutedSubtext__link" href="https://test.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
            <button type="submit">Webinar Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**THE PHP?:**

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["user_first_name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["user[email]"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I truly thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: when you define your `name` attribute as `name="user[email]"`, you effectively nest it in another dimension, so call it `$_GET['user']['email']` like so

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are on the right track, but there are some changes which needs to be done:

**HTML**

Change button:

```
<div class="Column">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Webinar Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

**test.php**

As far as your action method is `post` you should catch the request with the `$_POST`,

> Also since you are not using any `arrays` in your form, i do not see
>   any reason to use name for inputs like `name[first_name]`, it is just
>   easy to read and work with the code when it is named like
>   `first_name`.

```
<?php
$name = $email = "Nobody";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//check if form was submitted
   $name = $_POST["user"][first_name];
   $email = $_POST["user"][email];
} else {
     //redirect to home page
}
?>
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $name; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $email; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your php file should be like

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET['user_first_name']; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET['user']['name']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When you assign the name as `user[email]` php takes it as multi-dimensional array you can check the posted data by `print_r $_POST;` and you will get to know the method behind it.